# How do I web scrape the names of the production companies from IMDB website

Tags: python, web-scraping, imdb

I need to scrape the names of the ***Production Companies*** of some movies. I keep try by using the anchor tag `a` and the class in which the names are enclosed but it does not return the production companies.

URL : https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473553/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Here's the HTML part of the website that I want to scrape :

```
<section class="ipc-page-section ipc-page-section--base">
  <div data-testid="title-details-section" class="styles__MetaDataContainer-sc-12uhu9s-0 cgqHBf">
    <ul>
      <li role="presentation" class="ipc-metadata-list__item ipc-metadata-list-item--link" data-testid="title-details-companies"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__label ipc-metadata-list-item__label--link" rel="" href="/title/tt0473553/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co" target="">Production companies</a>
        <div class="ipc-metadata-list-item__content-container">
          <ul class="ipc-inline-list ipc-inline-list--show-dividers ipc-inline-list--inline ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content base" role="presentation">
            <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item">
                <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0136980?ref_=tt_dt_co_1">IDT Entertainment</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item">
                <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0142161?ref_=tt_dt_co_2">New Arc Entertainment</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's, What I have tried :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

movie_url="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473553/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1"
movie_page = requests.get(movie_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#movies_comp = soup.find_all("li", class_="ipc-inline-list__item")
movies_comp = soup.find_all("a", class_="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link")

print(movies_comp)
```

I am not getting desirable output. What I am expecting it to return output is like:

```
['IDT Entertainment', 'New Arc Entertainment']
```

Comment: @deceze I have edited the question. Will this be enough? I am trying to answer it.

Comment: @Xitiz A sample of the HTML being parsed would be needed here, that can't be an external link, as it's not guaranteed that we're even seeing the same HTML as OP sees.

Comment: @deceze Then, I believe edit from me only will not be enough, right?

Comment: @Xitiz Indeed, the question still doesn't provide all the necessary information to reproduce the problem in a self-contained manner.

Comment: But I have solved it, so I am confused what should I do?. _I was writing the answer but while posting, answer it said question is already closed._ I had faced this type of problem few other time as well. @deceze :(

Comment: @Xitiz Can you rewrite the question into a *minimal reproducible example* that doesn't depend on external websites? Or at least provides a sample of what that website looks like? Theoretically you'd just need to provide a small HTML string and remove the `requests` stuff…

Comment: @deceze Web scraping's question, can really be like this _doesn't depend on external websites_ ? I don't think so. But anyway I had added the HTML part.

Comment: @Xitiz Questions are for future visitors too, and if it depends on external websites to even *understand* the question, then 1) those websites may and likely will change in the future and obsolete the question, and 2) would force visitors to visit those external websites and inspect them to even understand whether the question and solution applies to them. Web scraping questions aren't an exception here. And yes, with this given sample, the question can now be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try :

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473553/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1")

page="""
<section class="ipc-page-section ipc-page-section--base">
  <div data-testid="title-details-section" class="styles__MetaDataContainer-sc-12uhu9s-0 cgqHBf">
    <ul>
      <li role="presentation" class="ipc-metadata-list__item ipc-metadata-list-item--link" data-testid="title-details-companies"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__label ipc-metadata-list-item__label--link" rel="" href="/title/tt0473553/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co" target="">Production companies</a>
        <div class="ipc-metadata-list-item__content-container">
          <ul class="ipc-inline-list ipc-inline-list--show-dividers ipc-inline-list--inline ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content base" role="presentation">
            <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item">
                <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0136980?ref_=tt_dt_co_1">IDT Entertainment</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item">
                <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0142161?ref_=tt_dt_co_2">New Arc Entertainment</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")

# To understand this is then structur of the data you want to extract :
# <li role="presentation" class="ipc-metadata-list__item ipc-metadata-list-item--link" data-testid="title-details-companies">
    # <ul class="ipc-inline-list ipc-inline-list--show-dividers ipc-inline-list--inline ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content base" role="presentation"><li role="presentation" class="ipc-inline-list__item"><a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0136980?ref_=tt_dt_co_1">
        # <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0136980?ref_=tt_dt_co_1">IDT Entertainment</a>
        # <a class="ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link" rel="" href="/company/co0142161?ref_=tt_dt_co_2">New Arc Entertainment</a>

print([a.text for a in soup.find("li",attrs={'class':r'ipc-metadata-list__item ipc-metadata-list-item--link','data-testid':r'title-details-companies'})
                                .find("ul",class_="ipc-inline-list ipc-inline-list--show-dividers ipc-inline-list--inline ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content base")
                                    .find_all("a")])
```

Output :

```
['IDT Entertainment', 'New Arc Entertainment']
```

There are `<a>` with that `class` so, you are getting multiple of them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this is specifically for one movie only. I want to do the same for a list of movies. This will return the same output for every movie.

Comment: Remove that page variable!

Comment: Okay let me try that